# Convert letters into numbers (A=1, B=2 etc)

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-2.x

```
class Names:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.numname = name
        for letter in name:
            self.numname = re.sub(letter, rosetta[letter] + ",", self.numname)
        self.numname = self.numname.split(',')[:-1]
```

Essentially what this does is creates an attribute for the object called 'numname' which is his/her name converted into numbers (A = 1, B = 2 This is stored in a dictionary called 'rosetta')  and stores each number as an element in a list. It *works* but it feels really inefficient. The problems I see here are:

- `self.numname` is called quite a lot. (Maybe it's possible to use list comprehension here?)
- `re.sub` is called per letter. I'd imagine this is unavoidable, however if a name had repeated letters (e.g. Matt). I tried using `''.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(self.numname)` in the third field of `re.sub` but then that screws up the number separation.

How can I make the creation of this list more concise/more permanent?

Comment: What is the last letter you support? 'Z'? Can you write anything beyond Z? Also, where / how do you define that `rosetta` ?

Comment: You should consider memo-izing the results of numname if you are likely to have repeats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like:

```
self.numname = [rosetta[x] for x in self.name]
```

This creates the list of numbers directly from the letters in the name, using a list comprehension.

Comment: This worked perfectly!